# Count number of child records using SOQL Aggregate

Tags: trigger, soql, count

I am new to this and I hope someone can help me with this.

What my aim is to count the number of `AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c` records with a date value on `Last_Activity__c` field on `AVTRRT__Job_Applicants__c` object that is associated to `AVTRRT__Job__c` and place the total count on the field called `Number_of_Applicants_with_Activities__c` on `AVTRRT__Job__c` object.

I think Agrgregate SOQL is the only option I have since using the code below conflicts with another trigger as it causes continues loop.

```
trigger DerekRollUp on AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
  Map<Id,AVTRRT__Job__c> updateJob = new Map<Id,AVTRRT__Job__c>();
  Set<Id> updateJobIds = new Set<Id>();
  // If we are inserting, updating, or undeleting, use the new ID values
  if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete)
    for(AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c applicant:Trigger.new)
      updateJobIds.add(applicant.AVTRRT__Job__c);
  // If we are updating, some Jobs might change, so include that as well as deletes
  if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete)
    for(AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c applicant:Trigger.old)
      updateJobIds.add(applicant.AVTRRT__Job__c);
  // Do not create a record for null field
  updateJobIds.remove(null);
  // Create in-memory copies for all Jobs that will be affected
  for(Id JobId:updateJobIds)
    updateJob.put(JobId,new AVTRRT__Job__c(id=JobId,Number_of_Applicants_with_Activities__c=0));
  // Run an optimized query that looks for all Jobs that meet the if/then criteria
  for(AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c applicant:[select id,AVTRRT__Job__c from AVTRRT__Job_Applicant__c where AVTRRT__Job__r.Id in :updateJobIds and Last_Activity_Date__c !=null])
    updateJob.get(applicant.AVTRRT__Job__c).Number_of_Applicants_with_Activities__c++;
  // Update all the Jobs with new values.
  Database.update(updateJob.values());
}
```

Comment: what is the relationship between `AVTRRT__Job_Applicants__c` and `AVTRRT__Job__c`? Who is parent and child?

Comment: Hope this link will help you - http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/

Comment: Is the relationship between Job and Job applicants master detail? If yes, then you could proceed with rollup summary fields with condition.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the relationship between Job and Job Applicant is that of a Master Detail. i.e. 1 Job will have multiple Job Applicants and applicants cannot exist without a Job. Assuming this is true you could do the following using roll up summary fields

1. Create a new Rollup Summary field called Applicant Count on the AVTRRT__Job__c object.
2. Use COUNT() as the aggregate option
3. In the FIlters section you could set the criteria as Last_Activity__c "not equal to" BLANK.

Add the Applicant Count field to page layout and you should be good. If the relationship between Job Applicant and Job is a Lookup then the trigger would be the way to go. However you could check this free appexchange app which allows rolling up field values with Lookup relationships. [Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI)
almost eradicates the need to write triggers for the similar redundant requirement of summarizing fields between objects related using a Lookup relationship.